# What happens when a MemoryCache object exceeds its CacheMemoryLimit?

Tags: caching, .net-4.0

When an instance of System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache (.NET 4.0) exceeds its CacheMemoryLimit, are all cache entries removed, or just some of them?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it should just be some of them.  However, I've had some issues with items not being evicted at all -- which [I seem to have tracked down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655439/net-4-memorycache-leaks-with-concurrent-garbage-collection) to the new garbage collection configuration options in .Net 4.  It won't ever be all of them, though.